# Are there infinitely many involutory matrices of order n?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Are there infinitely many involutory matrices of order n?

For $n=2$, I considered the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\ \end{bmatrix}$.
$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\r&s\\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p^2+qr&pq+qs\\rp+sr&rq+s^2\\ \end{bmatrix}$$
So the matrix $A$ is an involutory matrix only if,
$$pq+qs=0\\rp+sr=0\\p^2+qr=1\\rq+s^2=1$$
It is easy to see that $(p,q,r,s)=(1,0,k,-1)$ satisfies the above for equations for all $k\in \mathbb{R}$.
So the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\k&-1\\ \end{bmatrix}$ is involutory for all values for real values of $k$.

For $n>2$ simply multiplying the matrices makes things complicated. So is there any other way to prove that there are  infinitely many involutory matrix of order n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same construction with larger matrices,  just put a $1's$ on the main diagonal and a $k$ in the bottom left.  You can do any mixture of $1$ and $-1$ actually on the main diagonal

Comment: @Asher2211 Fixed.  Basically all the eigenvalues should be +/- 1

Comment: No,  you can have any parity on the main diagonal. all positive, all negative, any mix.

Comment: Suppose $a_{11}=1$ and $ a_{nn}=1$ then isn't $a_{n1}=2k$

Comment: @Asher2211 https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C-1%7D%7D%5E2  .  You can write it out to see why.

Comment: what about https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C1%7D%7D%5E2